# Getting max values for columns and join them with another table

Tags: sql, hana

I am new in SQL queries. I am planning to join 2 tables in HANA Express and get max value of two columns of one table and join it with another table. Here is scenario:

```
Table A
+-----+----------------+
| Key |     Value      |
+-----+----------------+
|   1 | Value is 1     |
|   2 | Value is 2     |
|   3 | Value is 3     |
+-----+----------------+

Table B
+-----+----------------------------+------+
| Seq |         Timestamp          | Key  |
+-----+----------------------------+------+
| 500 | Feb 3, 2017 6:35:59.742 PM |    1 |
| 501 | Feb 3, 2017 6:35:59.742 PM |    2 |
| 502 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:05.758 PM |    2 |
| 503 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:05.758 PM |    4 |
| 504 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:05.758 PM |    3 |
| 505 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:09.766 PM |    5 |
+-----+----------------------------+------+

output table
+-----+------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Key |   Value    | MaxSeq |      LatestTimeStamp       |          ExecutionTime          |
+-----+------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
|   1 | Value is 1 |    505 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:09.766 PM | (execution time of this query) |
|   2 | Value is 2 |    505 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:09.766 PM | (execution time of this query) |
|   3 | Value is 3 |    505 | Feb 3, 2017 6:36:09.766 PM | (execution time of this query) |
+-----+------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

So here the MaxSeq would be max value of Seq column in table B and LatestTimeStamp is the latest timestamp of the timestamp column of table B and both of them would be constant in the joined table. The execution time calculated from `Current_Timestamp` function in HANA. is it even possible?

Comment: And `ExecutionTime`?  Either explain how it is calculated or remove it from he question.

Comment: thanks. added the execution time explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.Key, a.Value, 
(select max(Seq) from TableB) MaxSeq,
```

(select max(Timestamp) from TableB)  c LatestTimestamp, ??? Executiontime
    from TableA

Even better:

```
select a.Key, a.Value, b.MaxSeq, b.LatestTimestamp , 
Current_Timestamp - b.LatestTimestamp Executiontime
from TableA, 
 (select max(Seq) MaxSeq,  max(Timestamp) LatestTimestamp from TableB) b
```

Comment: thanks but this query is generating max seq for each key value. not the max value of seq column in table b which will be a constant

Comment: I see, you don't want the max for every key, just the max for the table. Not sure why you'd want that but I'll edit my answer accordingly.